# Sequelize: Is there any way to amend an object when it's pulled out of a table?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have a Users table, and an array of emails (fetched from a different database) that denote whether or not an email is premium.

I'd like my ORM to attach `user.premium` every time it pulls a user out of the db. All it has to do is `user.premium = premiumEmails.includes(user.email)`

I was able to use the `afterFind` hook to do this exact action and it works when I use `User.findOne` or `User.find`, but NOT when I get a user through a relation.

When I do `Post.find`, I'd like Sequelize to look at `post.user` and attach the same `premium` field to the user that belongs to the post.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/4627) with Sequelize, and given the lack of recent activity on the linked GitHub issue, I don't think this will be fixed anytime soon.

Your best bet is to define a [Virtual field](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/getters-setters-virtuals.html#virtual-fields) on the user model that returns `premiumEmails.includes(this.email)` (note the use of `this` rather than `user`).

Comment: Virtual field was the perfect solution. Thanks!